# Closed expression for $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}k^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have to perform the following power sum in my embedded device

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}({x[n]})^2 \tag1$$ with $x[n] = 0,1,2,3...(N-1)$

Hence, I think that I can rewrite above power sum as

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}({k})^2 \tag2$$

Therefore, I was looking a closed expression for $(2)$ power sum, I came across to $(3)$ via [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html)

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^2} = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1) \tag 3$$

So I was wondering whether I can obtain the closed expression to $(2)$ via $(3)$ replacing $n = N-1$ as follows

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{k^2} = \frac{1}{6}(N-1) \bigl((N-1)+1\bigr)\bigl(2(N-1)+1)\bigr) \tag 3$$

or would I be doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's fine as starting your sum by 0 or 1 does not change anything.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas